# Very dull raster colors on folium map

Tags: python, raster, folium, geotiff, rasterio

I have a 4 band image (R,G,B,NIR) and I would like to print it on a folium map, but the result is not the same as what you see on QGIS, the image is very opaque and the colors very dull and I thought stretching the image might help. Can you help me?
I report the code used.
Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import folium
import rasterio

with rio.open(raster) as src:
    img = src.read()
    meta = src.meta
    meta['nodata'] = np.nan
    min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = src.bounds

meta

{'driver': 'GTiff',
 'dtype': 'float64',
 'nodata': nan,
 'width': 52,
 'height': 28,
 'count': 4,
 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326),
 'transform': Affine(0.00011284198076925242, 0.0, 12.026403058,
        0.0, -0.0001128420000000574, 44.289920142)}
    
bounds_orig = [[min_lat, min_lon], [max_lat, max_lon]]
centerx,centery = (np.average((min_lon,max_lon)),np.average((min_lat,max_lat)))

m = folium.Map(location = [centery,centerx], tiles='OpenStreetMap', zoom_start = 17)

vmin, vmax = np.nanpercentile(img.transpose(1, 2, 0), (10,90))

m.add_child( folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(img.transpose(1, 2, 0),name = 'raster',
                                              bounds = bounds_orig,opacity=1,
                                               colormap=[vmin,vmax]))
```

Folium result
[image]

QGIS result

[image]

Comment: The [folium raster_layers doc](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#module-folium.raster_layers) says `colormap:
Function of the form [x -> (r,g,b)] or [x -> (r,g,b,a)] 
for transforming a mono image into RGB`. But your image is not mono i.e. 2d, and your colormap is not a function at all -- I'd have expected TypeError.